# Split a mixed string

Tags: r, regex

I have trouble splitting a mixed string. There are two situations considered:

1. split `"A1BB2CCC3"` into `"A1" "BB2" "CCC3"`.
2. split the same thing into `"A" "1" "BB" "2" "CCC" "3"`.

I try to use `strsplit()` but I'm not familiar with **regex** syntax. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use split twice and paste/concatenate the two to get your situations, i.e.

```
i1 <- strsplit(x, '[0-9]+')[[1]]
i2 <- strsplit(x, '[A-Z]+')[[1]]

case1 <- paste0(i1, i2[i2 != ''])
case1
#[1] "A1"   "BB2"  "CCC3"

case2 <- c(i1, i2[i2 != ''])
case2
#[1] "A"   "BB"  "CCC" "1"   "2"   "3"
```

If order in `case2` is important, then we can use `Map`, i.e.

```
unlist(Map(c, i1, i2[i2 != '']))
# A1    A2   BB1   BB2  CCC1  CCC2 
#"A"   "1"  "BB"   "2" "CCC"   "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use only the `base` package, then `regmatches` and `gregexpr` can make it:

```
s <- "A1BB2CCC3"
r1 <- unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("([[:alpha:]]+\\d+)",s)))
r2 <- unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("([[:alpha:]]+)|(\\d+)",s)))
```

where

- `([[:alpha:]]+\\d+)` denotes the format of alphabet(s) followed by digit(s) as a group
- `([[:alpha:]]+)|(\\d+)` denotes the format of alphabet(s) or digit(s) as their own groups, respectively

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package. The first can be done:

```
str_extract_all("A1BB2CCC3","[A-Z]+[0-9]{1}")

[[1]]
[1] "A1"   "BB2"  "CCC3"
```

Were the pattern reads any number of upper case letter `[A-Z]+` followed by one number `[0-9]{1}`.
the second:

```
str_extract_all("A1BB2CCC3","[A-Z]+|[0-9]")

[[1]]
[1] "A"   "1"   "BB"  "2"   "CCC" "3"
```

the pattern is any upper case letters or a number.

Answer (score 0):

Less eloquent then the other answers - and using at @Sotos Map function:

```
tmp <- "A1BB2CCC3"
combined_elements <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(trimws(gsub("\\d+", " ", tmp), "both"), "\\s+")),

              unlist(strsplit(trimws(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", " ", tmp), "both"), "\\s+")))

unlist(Map(c, unlist(strsplit(trimws(gsub("\\d+", " ", tmp), "both"), "\\s+")), 
           unlist(strsplit(trimws(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", " ", tmp), "both"), "\\s+"))))
```